# Python threading in web programming

Tags: python, thread-safety

I face a potential race condition in a web application:

```
# get the submissions so far from the cache
submissions = cache.get('user_data')
# add the data from this user to the local dict
submissions[user_id] = submission

# update the cached dict on server
submissions = cache.update('user_data', submissions)

if len(submissions) == some_number:
    ...
```

The logic is simple, we first fetch a shared dictionary stored in the cache of web server, add the submission (delivered by each request to the server) to its local copy, and then we update the cached copy by replacing it with this updated local copy. Finally we do something else if we have received a certain number of pieces of data. Notice that

```
submissions = cache.update('user_data', submissions)
```

will return the latest copy of dictionary from the cache, i.e. the newly updated one.

Because the server may serve multiple requests (each in its own thread) at the same time, and all these threads access the shared dictionary in cache as described above, thus creating potential race conditions.

I wonder, in the context of web programming, how should I **efficiently** handle threading to prevent race conditions in this particular case, **without sacrificing too much performance**. Some code examples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred solution would be to have a single thread that modifies the submissions dict and a queue that feed that thread. If you are paranoid, you can even expose a read-only view on the submissions dict. Using a queue and consumer pattern, you will not have a problem with locking.

Of course, this assumes that you have a web framework that will let you create that thread.

EDIT: multiprocess was not a good suggestion; removed.

EDIT: This sort of stuff is really simple in Python:

```
import threading, Queue

Stop = object()

def consumer(real_dict, queue):
    while True:
        try:
            item = queue.get(timeout=100)
            if item == Stop:
                break
            user, submission = item
            real_dict[user] = submission
        except Queue.Empty:
            continue

q = Queue.Queue()
thedict={}

t = threading.Thread(target=consumer, args=(thedict,q,))
t.start()
```

Then, you can try:

```
>>> thedict
{}
>>> q.put(('foo', 'bar'))
>>> thedict
{'foo': 'bar'}
>>> q.put(Stop)
>>> q.put(('baz', 'bar'))
>>> thedict
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm very interested in finding more about this approach. Could you please provide some psuedo-code illustration of the ideas (e.g. single thread, queue, and how they interact) above?In addition, what exactly do you mean by a 'read-only view' here ('submissions' is a dict stored in cache not in db)? The framework I'm using is a Model-View-Controller framework, if that matters. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be transferring lots of data back and forth between your web application and your cache. That's *already* a problem. You're also right to be suspicious, since it would be *possible* for the pattern to be like this (remembering that `sub` is local to each thread):

```
Thread A        Thread B        Cache
--------------------------------------------
                                [A]=P, [B]=Q
sub = get()
   [A]=P, [B]=Q
>>>> suspend
                sub = get()
                   [A]=P, [B]=Q
                sub[B] = Y
                   [A]=P, [B]=Y
                update(sub)
                                [A]=P, [B]=Y
                >>>> suspend
sub[A] = X
   [A]=X, [B]=Q
update(sub)
                                [A]=X, [B]=Q         !!!!!!!!
```

This sort of pattern can happen for real, and it results in state getting wiped out. It's also inefficient because thread A should usually only need to know about its current user, not everything.

While you could fix this by great big gobs of locking, that would be horribly inefficient. So, you need to redesign so that you transfer much less data around, which will give a performance boost and reduce the amount of locking you need.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I am transferring data back and forth between the cache and my app is that I need to keep track of a 'global variable' among different users, which records the their submissions up to any point of time, and do something to it once it gets to certain size. I admit that the cache approach might not be ideal, but I can't really think of any other alternative design (except for replacing cache for database, which may be arguably even more expensive). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the more difficult questions to answer because it seems to be a bigger design problem.

One potential solution to this problem would be to have one well-defined place where this is updated.  For instance, you might want to set up another service that's dedicated to updating the cache and nothing else.  Alternatively, if these updates aren't time-sensitive, you may also want to consider using a task queue.

Another solution: you could give each item a separate key and store a list of the keys under a separate key.  This doesn't necessarily *solve* the problem, but it does make it more manageable.  Instead of worrying about separate threads overwriting the entire submissions cache, you just have to worry about them overwriting individual elements within it.

If you have the time to add a new piece to your infrastructure, I'd highly recommend looking at [Redis](http://redis.io), more specifically [Redis hashes](http://degizmo.com/2010/03/24/redis-relations-in-a-nosql-world-using-hashes/)[1].  The reason being that Redis handles this problem out of the box, with about the same speed as you'd get with memcache (although I definitely encourage you to benchmark it for yourself).

[1] Note:  I just found this link through a quick Google search, and haven't verified it.  I don't vouch for its correctness.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into the Redis option a bit more. Regarding the other solution (separate key for each item and a separate key for the list of the keys), how is that different from the current approach (where each item is stored by a key-value pair in a dictionary, and the dictionary itself is stored in the cache with a key)? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @skyork - I suppose it doesn't necessarily *solve* the problem per se, but it does limit its scope.  Now you don't have to worry about separate threads overwriting the entire dictionary.  You just have to worry about them modifying the same entry at the same time, which is a much more manageable problem to solve.

Comment: Thanks Jason. So if I understand you correctly, you are suggesting that I store each item as a (user_id, submission) pair in the cache, and store a key-value pair for (some_key, [list_of_stored_user_ids]) separately in the cache too. While this does ensure that all the (user_id, submission) pairs will be stored consistently in the cache, (some_key, [list_of_stored_user_ids]) key-value pair still faces potential race condition, as in the original dictionary approach. And I need to use the correct list fo retrieving the submissions. Please correct me if I've misunderstood your idea. Thanks.